# Assigning label per row through an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, row

I got the following array:

```
array([['A', 0.05],
       ['B', 0.09],
       ['C', 0.13]]
```

I want to make a new column and assign a label to the items A, B and C, based on the second column. 
If the item is above 0.10, it has to get the label '2'. If it is below 0.10, it has to get the label '1'. So my desired output is:

```
 array([['A', 0.05,'1'],
        ['B', 0.09,'1'],
        ['C', 0.13,'2']]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is that a numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) combined with [numpy.column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([['A', 0.05],
                ['B', 0.09],
                ['C', 0.13]])

col = np.where(arr[:, 1].astype(np.float) > 0.10, '2', '1')
arr = np.column_stack((arr, col))
print(arr)
```

**Output**

```
[['A' '0.05' '1']
 ['B' '0.09' '1']
 ['C' '0.13' '2']]
```

**UPDATE**

If you have more than two labels, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([['A', 0.05],
                ['B', 0.09],
                ['C', 0.13]])

def calc(x):
    if x < 0.08:
        return '1'
    elif 0.08 <= x < 0.10:
        return '2'
    elif 0.10 < x:
        return '3'


col = np.array([calc(e) for e in arr[:, 1].astype(np.float)])
arr = np.column_stack((arr, col))
print(arr)
```

**Output**

```
[['A' '0.05' '1']
 ['B' '0.09' '2']
 ['C' '0.13' '3']]
```

Comment: thanks! And what do I do when i want to make 3 classes, where I say; if A, B, or C is below 0.08, then it has to get the label '1', if it is higher than 0.10, it has to get label '3' and everything in between has to get the label '2'?

Comment: I would suggest creating a function that maps the intervals to the labels and apply it to every element in the array.

Comment: I now did that: my function is called 'calc(x)', where x is the value of 0.05, 0.09, etc. But i'm struggling to add this into the code you provided. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @StevenPauly Updated the answer to include a solution for more than two labels.

Comment: thanks!! all makes sense now

Comment: all makes sense now - except when x is 0.1, maybe that last elif should be 0.10 <= x: